# salt vs. iv for PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

Understanding that `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC()` requires a ***salt*** and gives back a *derivedKey*

And that `GCM<AES>::Encryption.SetKeyWithIV()` requires an ***iv*** (along with the *derivedKey*)

Is it safe to use the same value for ***salt*** (in `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC()`) and ***iv*** (in `GCM<AES>::Encryption.SetKeyWithIV()`) - or should they be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to use the same value for salt (in PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC()) and iv (in GCM::Encryption.SetKeyWithIV()) - or should they be different?

Yes and no. *Yes* - you can use the output of `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC` to generate a salt, iv or key. *No* - you should not reuse parameters like that.

Often, you do something like below. It uses unique labels, so derived parameters cannot be the same.

```
string password = "super secret password;
string label = "Key derivation with IV";
size_t length = password.length() + label.length();
unsigned int count = 5000;

SecByteBlock key(32 /*Key*/ + 16 /*IV*/);

PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<SHA1> pbkdf2;
pbkdf2.DeriveKey(key, key.size(), 0, (unsigned char*)(password + label).data(), length,
    NULL /*salt*/, 0 /*salt length*/, count);

GCM<AES>::Encryption encryptor;
encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(key, 32, key+32, 16);
```

The label above help makes the derivation unique.

If you derive for a salt, your label might be `"Salt derivation for X"`. In this case, you will get different values from the KDF.

In the above, its OK to apply the KDF twice. First, apply it with no salt to create a salt (using a unique label). Second, using the salt to derive a key and iv (using the previous generated salt and a unique label).

Comment: Practically speaking, I would make label random per-encryption but store it in plaintext alongside the ciphertext- essentially using it like an iv/salt (but still only requiring to store that one value- since the other iv will be derived from the KDF)?

Comment: @David - yes, that should be fine, too.

Comment: here's what I ended up with... tried to make it use std::string less since it's confusing for me to see that and think it's raw bytes ;)

http://pastebin.com/cPtqcP60

(ByteArray is just a struct to hold a pointer and length of data and free the data when deleted)

Comment: wasn't quite sure how to use BitBucket or ArraySink instead of StringSink- so left that part in

Comment: @David - `BitBucket` is a sink that simply discards output. Its like sending something to `/dev/null`.